# Exponential of formal power series and Bell polynomials

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, analysis, reference-request, power-series

Wikipedia gives [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials) the following formula for the exponential of a formal power series:

$\exp \Big[\  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n\ \Big] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n(a_1,\dots,a_n)}{n!} x^n$

where $B_n$ are (complete) Bell-polynomials. Can anybody give me a ("standard") reference for this?

Comment: This is more or less a definition of the Bell polynomials. What definition are you working from?

Comment: Thanks @Qiachou Yuan, I see it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generating function version can be found in Herb Wilf's book Generatingfunctionology (which is available as a pdf for free, just google it).  It is around section 1.6 (among other places, I believe).

Answer (score 3):

A further reference is:

Comtet, Louis: Advanced combinatorics; the art of finite and infinite expansions. Reidel, 1974.