Comparing coefficients in double summation series
I have a function that is given by two unique series summations. The first representation is given as,
$$
F(k) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (k a)^{2n}}{n!} \left( \sum_{m=0}^\infty b_m \; (k a)^{2m}\right)^n
$$
The second representation is in a different form given by,
$$
F(k)  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n k^{2n}}{n!} \left< \tau^n \right>
$$
I want to compare the powers of $k$ in the above two equations to obtain a general formula for $\left< \tau^n \right>$,
$$
\left< \tau^n \right> = G(a,b_m,\cdots)
$$
Rather than explicitly writing out the each of the terms by expanding the series entirely, is there a slick way to calculate any $n^{th}$ moment of $\tau$?
Notes: Consider all variables to be real. Moreover, it can be considered that $a > 0$

I would first simplify the notations, letting $x:=-(ka)^2,c_m:=(-1)^mb_m,\left< \tau^n \right>=a^{2n}\sigma_n$ and
$$\exp\left( \sum_{m=0}^\infty c_mx^{m+1}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\sigma_n.$$

Then, let $a_{m+1}:=(m+1)!,c_m$ and use Bell polynomials. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147790
